# undefined method `encrypted_latitude' for #<Location:0x007f574a4eef50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption-symmetric, attr-accessible

Hi I am using symmetric encryption [(This one)](https://github.com/reidmorrison/symmetric-encryption) gem to encrypt some fields. I have generated all the keys and followed all the steps given in it. But When I am trying to save data on my server it throws error on these lines

```
 attr_encrypted :latitude
 attr_encrypted :longitude
```

Error is

```
undefined method `encrypted_latitude' for #<Location:0x007f574a4eef50>
```

I have checked types, steps for gem and all looks fine. 
Any idea what I am missing ...all works when I removed these lines from model. In Addition I have added attr_accessible for both fields and protected_attributes gem to make attr_accessible work

Any idea where I went wrong..Thanks

Comment: is the column name `encrypted_latitude` in your table?

Comment: Have you heard of [Virtual attributes](http://hibbard.eu/using-virtual-attributes-in-rails-3/).

Comment: no I did not ...but is it somthing in this case

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may not have got a single instance of location. Do you have first at the end of the query?

i.e.

```
lat = Latitude.where( query ).first
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the column named `encrypted_latitude` is not available in your `locations` table.

From the [doc](https://github.com/reidmorrison/symmetric-encryption):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Requires table users to have a column called encrypted_bank_account_number
  attr_encrypted :bank_account_number
```

Comment: that means I need to add encrypted_latitude field in table ..which does not make sense coz I want to encrypt those field not to keep both normal and encrypted in different fields...in same table

Comment: rename latitude field to encrypted_latitude. normal value will not be stored.

Comment: ahh..ok thanks ...I try that and accepts answer ...:)